# Why is it that in a warm shower water feels hotter near the head?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, temperature

When the water first hits your body, it feels warmer than when it streams down towards your feet. I realize that part of this is due to the water cooling down by dissipation to the surrounding as it falls. But as the water loses gravitational potential energy shouldn't it also gain kinetic energy (heat)? Is the dissipation rate too great for the gain of kinetic energy to balance out?

Comment: For the most part, humans don't feel temperature.  Our sense of heat is more like the flux (flow) of heat into our skin.  If you hold temperature constant but change how well it transfers to the body, the thing will feel hotter/colder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even assuming all of the energy it gains is turned into thermal energy (heat) it's just too small to worry about.

$$\Delta KE = mg \Delta h$$
Let's assume it falls $2m$. 
$$\Delta KE = mg (2m)$$
Given that energy, we can compute the heating of the water.
$$ Q = m C_p \Delta T$$
$$ \Delta T = \frac{Q}{mC_p}$$
$C_p$ for water is $4.18 \frac{J}{gK}$
$$\Delta T = \frac{m(9.81\frac{m}{s})(2m)}{m(4.18\frac{J}{gK})} $$
$$\Delta T = \frac{19.62 \frac{m^2}{s^2}}{4180 \frac{m^2}{s^2K}}$$
$$\Delta T = 0.005K$$
Any mass of water dropping 2m, unless it can transfer the energy elsewhere will warm less than $1/100$ of a degree $C$.

Comment: What if you considered the world from the reference frame of the water droplet being stationary? This would make it appear as though everything else heated up instead.

Comment: Neither heats up while the drop is falling.  All of that (little) energy is stored in the form of kinetic (motion) energy.  It won't particularly heat up until it hits something and viscosity can dissipate that energy into heat.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature doesn't rise as an object falls. Temperature is just the average kinetic energy of the individual particles within an object, but their individual velocities is random. A water droplet falling is an ordered falling that you can consider as a form of work, and you feel it as the splattering on your feet.